# How can I find number of entries of a particular type within a given time period in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

The data is in the below attached format in excel. I want to find the number of cases of lets say divorce category from 2014-2016 year of reporting. Please suggest a formula for this

Comment: Try [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) or [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5).

Comment: yes its the same, thanks for your help :)